# I need to Count the Number of Columns that have value more than 0 in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to create a calculated field at the end of the columns where it will count all the Columns having values greater than 0.

Below is a sample Data Set.

```
Account_number  DAY_0 DAY_30 DAY_60 DAY_90 DAY_120
acc_001           99     10      0      0.2     0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Will Definitely do from my next question onwards, This was my first question and I'm still exploring. Thanks for the Advice.

Comment: . . You can edit this question and add the tag.  Or specify the database in a comment and someone else might do it fory ou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when day_0 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when day_30 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when day_60 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when day_90 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when day_120 > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as num_gt_zero
from t;
```

That said, you probably constructed this from a `group by` query.  You might be able to put this logic directly into that query.  If that is the case, ask a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. Your solution worked for me.